# Rails Deleting model object via AJAX

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, button, destroy

I'm trying to remotely destroy an object using Ajax. This is what I've done:

This is the destroy action in ProductsController

```
  def destroy
    @product = Product.find(params[:id])
    @product.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html {redirect_to products_path, success: 'Product destroyed successfully'}
      format.js {}
    end
  end
```

This is the destroy.js.erb inside products views

```
$(this).closest('tr').remove()
```

The interaction with the button is in a page with the following templates:
Index template:

```
<table class="table table-hover products">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Sell</th>
      <th>Delete</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <%= render @products %>
  </tbody>
</table>
<br/>
<br/>
```

This is _product template

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <%= link_to product.title, edit_product_path(product) %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= product.stock %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= product.cost %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= product.price %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= button_to 'Sell Product', new_product_sale_path(product), method: :get, class: 'btn btn-secondary' %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= button_to "Delete Product", product_path(product), remote: true, 
                                method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

The destroy works, but the html is not updated accordingly. What am I missing ? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`this` in delete.js.erb makes no sense. You will have to somehow mark each row uniquely, by id for example.

Your _product template gonna look like:

```
<tr id="row_<%= product_id %>">
    <td>
      <%= link_to product.title, edit_product_path(product) %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= product.stock %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= product.cost %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= product.price %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= button_to 'Sell Product', new_product_sale_path(product), method: :get, class: 'btn btn-secondary' %>
    </td>
    <td>
      <%= button_to "Delete Product", product_path(product), remote: true, 
                                  method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
    </td>
</tr>
```

And your destroy.js.erb should look like

```
$("#row_<%= @product.id %>").remove();
```

I hope you get the point.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice using DOMid to locate which element you are trying to delete. for example: `<tr id='<%= dom_id(product)%>'>` and in your destroy.js.erb `$('#<%= dom_id(@product) %>').remove()`

Answer (score 1):

Actually, `this` is a reference of object, so it won't be available, in destroy.js.erb.
You may give unique `id` to each tr in product partial.

eg:

```html
<tr id="product_<%= product.id %>" >
  <td>
    <%= link_to product.title, edit_product_path(product) %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= product.stock %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= product.cost %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= product.price %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= button_to 'Sell Product', new_product_sale_path(product), method: :get, class: 'btn btn-secondary' %>
  </td>
  <td>
    <%= button_to "Delete Product", product_path(product), remote: true, 
                                method: :delete, data: { confirm: "Are you sure?" }, class: "btn btn-secondary" %>
  </td>
</tr>
```

And, in destroy.js.erb, write following code. It will definite help you.

```js
$("#product_<%=@product.id%>").remove();
```